# NSRegularExpression not evaluating correctly

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following regular expression for passwords which evaluates correctly on online regex testers for Password.123:

```
/(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-z]*$)(?!^[A-Z]*$)(?!^[\\W]*$)(^[a-zA-Z0-9\\W]).{7,}/
```

When I make an NSRegularExpression in swift it evaluates incorrectly and cannot find a match for Password.123:

```
let password = "Password.123"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "/(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-z]*$)(?!^[A-Z]*$)(?!^[\\W]*$)(^[a-zA-Z0-9\\W]).{7,}/", options: [])

let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: password.count)
print("Valid: \(regex.firstMatch(in: password, options: [], range: range) != nil)")
```

This prints false but should be true. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `/`'s from your string? I.e. `let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-z]*$)(?!^[A-Z]*$)(?!^[\\W]*$)(^[a-zA-Z0-9\\W]).{7,}", options: [])`

Comment: Ah thanks, that was it

Comment: I'll make it the answer so that you can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `/`'s from your string. I.e.

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-z]*$)(?!^[A-Z]*$)(?!^[\\W]*$)(^[a-zA-Z0-‌​9\\W]).{7,}", options: [])
```